# Вопросы по web-приложению

Tags: flash, веб-программирование

Привет!кого не затруднит,можете ответить на впоросы
Надо создать подобное приложение такое как http://www.sxemka.com

1)с помощью чего можно создать такое приложение?

2)с помощью чего тут сделаны изображения(например,автомобиль сначала показывается сбоку,а когда ее переносишь на форму то она принимает вид сверху

Answer (score 3):

Здесь используется технология Flash.
А картинка с изображением автомобиля сбоку и сверху - это две разные картинки (спрайты, как их зовут в Flash)